# Python to java expressions in python 3

Tags: python

I have to write a program that can determine rather it is a python expression or a java expression. I am having a bit of trouble. I have tried serval ways and its not working.

Comment: & we are supposed to guess the code right ?

Comment: if (expression ends with ";") return "Java" else return "Python"

Comment: @tobias_k `1+1;` is valid python.

Comment: @timgeb That was meant as a joke. Seriously, I don't think there is any practical and reliable way, except maybe for actually trying to parse the code with Python or Java.

Comment: Maybe you should provide a few example "expressions" and what they should be recognized at. What exactly is an expression? A full line of code, or also something like `1+1`?

Comment: class python_or_java(self):
 


 def findtype(expr):
  for i in range (expr):
   c = i
   if (c < len(expr)-1):
    if (expr[c]== '/'and expr[c+1]=='/'):
     return Python
     
    elif (expr[c]== '*'and expr[c+1]=='*'):
     else:
      return JAVA
def main():
 
 
 
 
 
main():

Comment: Is this supposed to be your language checker, or an example for Python code to be recognized? `class python_or_java(self):`? `def main(): main():`? That's not even valid python. If you want to show us what you've tried so far (please do!) _edit_ your question, don't post complex code as a comment. Also we'd really appreciate some examples for "Python-" and "Java-Expressions"

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to determine this.
For example you can check the position of expressions used in other ways in java than in python. Like ":" and ";" or words like "public", "void" etc